# Return image with function show on *ngFor Angular 4

Tags: image, angular, function, service, components

I have a function in component.ts as follow:

```
getImage(name) {
  this._productService.getImage(name).subscribe((response) => {
  // ??? my problem is here
  });
}
```

and it's called here

```
        <tr *ngFor="let i of data">
          <td>{{ i.id }}</td>
          <td><img [src]="getImage(i.image)" alt=""></td>
          <td>{{ i.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ i.price }}</td>
        </tr>
```

So, how to my function return image?

P/S: my service get image from API ensure proper operation.

Thank for your help!

Comment: what you are planning to do inside the function `getImage()`

Comment: `getImage(i.name)` will return a image from Url that i have defined (
each url is an image and different by `i.name`)

Comment: what is the issue you have now?

Comment: I don't know how to the function in component returns an image?

Comment: are you available in teamviewer?

Comment: yes, 102 534 243 / 6529.

Comment: I do not speak English well.
sympathy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your onInit use the below code,

```
this._productService.index().subscribe((data) => {
      this.data = data;
      console.log(data);
    },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      },
      () => {
        this.data.forEach((element: IProduct) => {
          element.image = element.image === null ? '' : this._productService.getImage((element.image));
        });
      });
```

As worked in teamviwer